# Assign a value based on condition using Java Stream if present or else

Tags: java, lambda, java-stream, option-type

I want to set a value to a string if an Optional is present else get it from a list based on a condition. I have tried many ways but not able to get it. I am new to Streams so need help.

Basically my condition is this in traditional way -

```
        String rel = ""
        if(release.isPresent()){
            rel = release.get();
        }
        else{
            for(Release r: project.getReleases()){
                if(r.isActive() == true){
                    rel = r.getName();
                }
            }
        }
```

This is what I have written, but it doesn't work. I am getting error in the orElse part -

```
rel = release.ifPresent(r-> release.get())
                .orElse(
                    project.getReleases()
                    .stream()
                    .filter( r -> r.isActive() == true)
                    .findFirst()
                    .map(r->r.getName()));
```

Can you please suggest what is the correct way to do this ? Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: `r -> r.isActive() == true` => `r -> r.isActive` => `Release::isActive`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `Optional#orElseGet` for this

### Why `orElseGet` and not `orElse` ?

Because `orElseGet` accepts a `Supplier` which will only be invoked if your `Optional` is empty. So you won't have the overhead of `Stream` creation etc.

### Example

```java
String rel = release.orElseGet(() -> project.getReleases()
                                            .stream()
                                            .filter(Release::isActive)
                                            .map(Release::getName)
                                            .findFirst()
                                            .orElse(""));
```

Comment: This is perfect, Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 2):

This is what you want in case you use [java-9](/questions/tagged/java-9) or newer (I recommend you to tag the version used):

```
String rel = release
        .or(() -> project.getReleases().stream()
                                       .filter(Release::isActive)
                                       .map(Release::getName)
                                       .findFirst())
        .orElse("");
```

Basically `Optional#or` returns either the present value from the original `Optional` or provides a `Supplier<Optional>` providing such value in lazy way (will not be called in case the former value is present).

Use the advantage that `Stream#findFirst` returns `Optional` hence such call is compatible with the method needs. Finally call `orElse("")` as the last possible value if no usable value was present in the previous attempts.

Comment: This works too, looks like there are multiple ways of doing it or(), orElse(), orElseGet().

Comment: Very nice finding Nikolas !

Comment: @sana: I don’t recommend putting Stream into orElse() as it will be invoked everytime regardless whether the result is needed or not.

Answer (score 0):

you can do

```
release.orElse(project.getReleases()
               .stream().filter(Release::isActive).findFirst().map(Release::getName).orElse(""));
```

Comment: Hi @Deadpool, When the string release has value it works fine but when it doesn't it prints empty string. `project.getReleases().stream().filter(Release::isActive).findFirst().map(Release::getName).orElse("")` part alone works fine alone but when the string release is not having having value the the whole thing doesn't work. It prints blank.

Comment: Just to clarify, the first release is a value coming from the configuration. If the value from config is empty, it is supposed to take it from the project.getReleases() list. -
`@Value("${release.name}")
 private String release;`